# Floating-point computation without syscall?

Tags: linux-kernel, floating-point, system-calls

I am reading Robert Love's book on Linux kernel (which says no FP computation inside kernel). And I am wondering how floating point computation is done in user space.

For instance, does `3.14 + 5.26` (in C) invoke any syscall to do the job?

Comment: try to disassemble binary and you will see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On most modern processors, simple double addition such as `3.14 + 5.26` would be done by hardware commands, just like integer addition.

Comment: And on platforms that do not have floating-point support in hardware, one normally falls back on user-land emulation at the cost of 50-500 clock cycles per operation. I do not know what the minimum cost of a sycall is these days, but it used to be measured in 1000s of cycles last time I checked more than 10 years ago, so emulating floating-point operations in that fashion would be prohibitively expensive.

Comment: Note that when executing a binary that includes floating-point instructions on a processor that does not have any, execution can (could) go through floating-point emulation routines that happened to be inside the kernel. For instance Linux used to include these. It is not clear from this article whether they were removed at the same time as support for the 80386. http://www.zdnet.com/article/good-bye-386-linux-to-drop-support-for-i386-chips-with-next-major-release/